# Get point associated with Voronoi region (scipy.spatial.Voronoi)

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi

I'm generating a simple 2D Voronoi tessellation, using the [scipy.spatial.Voronoi](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) function. I use a random 2D distribution of points (see MCVE below).

I need a way to go through each defined region (defined by `scipy.spatial.Voronoi`) and get the coordinates of the point associated to it (ie: the point that said region encloses).

The issue is that there are `N+1` regions (polygons) defined for the `N` points, and I'm not sure what this means.

Here's a MCVE that will fail when it gets to the last region:

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
import numpy as np

# Generate random data.
N = 10
x = [np.random.random() for i in xrange(N)]
y = [np.random.random() for i in xrange(N)]
points = zip(x, y)

# Obtain Voronoi regions.
vor = Voronoi(points)

# Loop through each defined region/polygon
for i, reg in enumerate(vor.regions):

    print 'Region:', i
    print 'Indices of vertices of Voronoi region:', reg
    print 'Associated point:', points[i], '\n'
```

Another thing I don't understand is why are there empty `vor.regions` stored? According to the docs:

> regions: Indices of the Voronoi vertices forming each Voronoi region. -1 indicates vertex outside the Voronoi diagram.

What does an empty region mean?

---

**Add**

I tried the `point_region` attribute but apparently I don't understand how it works. It returns indexes outside of the range of the `points` list. For example: in the MCVE above it will always show an index `10` for a list of 10 points, which is clearly out of range.

Comment: `Voronoi` instances have a `point_region` attribute that does exactly what you are after. [Read the docs!](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html)

Comment: @Jaime I did try that attribute, please see what I added to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your first question:

> The issue is that there are N+1 regions (polygons) defined for the N points, and I'm not sure what this means.

This is because your vor.regions will always have an empty array. 
Something like

```
    [[],[0, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1]]
```

This is related to your second question:

> Another thing I don't understand is why are there empty vor.regions stored? According to the docs: regions: Indices of the Voronoi vertices forming each Voronoi region. -1 indicates vertex outside the Voronoi diagram.
>   **What does an empty region mean?**

By default Voronoi() uses QHull with options 'Qbb Qc Qz Qx' enabled ([qhull.org/html/qvoronoi.htm](http://qhull.org/html/qvoronoi.htm)). This inserts a "point-at-infinity" which is used to improve precision on circular inputs. Therefore, being a "fake" point, it has no region. If you want to get rid of this, try removing the Qz option:

```
vor = Voronoi(points, qhull_options='Qbb Qc Qx')
```

Answer (score 9):

I was misreading the docs. It says:

> point_region: *Index of the **Voronoi region** for each **input point***.

and I was using `point_region` it as if it were the: "*Index of the **input point** for each **Voronoi region***".

Instead of using:

```
points[i]
```

the correct point coordinates for each region can be obtained with:

```
np.where(vor.point_region == i)[0][0]
```

Comment: Did you figure out why certain `regions` are empty?  This [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/spatial.html#qhulltutorial) says "Note here that due to similar numerical precision issues as in Delaunay triangulation above, there may be fewer Voronoi regions than input points."  So I'm guessing that means qhull calculates Voronoi using Delaunay?  And "such degeneracies can occur not only because of duplicated points, but also for more complicated geometrical reasons, even in point sets that at first sight seem well-behaved"

Comment: But although I've seen how to hack around this problem, I'm still confused whether those solutions give you real answers or just keep "`regions`" from being empty.  I will keep looking.  Perhaps for my case I will just throw out the points that give empty regions

Comment: Unfortunately it's been a while since I used Voronoi regions in my research and I ended up not actually using them, so I can not give you any insight into what's going on. Perhaps you could ask over at https://math.stackexchange.com/ since it would appear to be an issue related to the properties of Voronoi regions rather than its implementation in Scipy?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  I believe it's actually the opposite, haha.  Voronoi should always have a region associated with a given point so long as that point is not a duplicate.  It seems to have something to do with qhull's implementation

Comment: I hope @aqueiros ' answer is correct, and these empty regions just belong to the points added at infinity

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotutils_moje import voronoi_plot_2d


class VoronoiRegion:
    def __init__(self, region_id):
        self.id = region_id
        self.vertices = []
        self.is_inf = False
        self.point_inside = None

    def __str__(self):
        text = f'region id={self.id}'
        if self.point_inside:
            point_idx, point = self.point_inside
            text = f'{text}[point:{point}(point_id:{point_idx})]'
        text += ', vertices: '
        if self.is_inf:
            text += '(inf)'
        for v in self.vertices:
            text += f'{v}'
        return text

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def add_vertex(self, vertex, vertices):
        if vertex == -1:
            self.is_inf = True
        else:
            point = vertices[vertex]
            self.vertices.append(point)

def voronoi_to_voronoi_regions(voronoi):
    voronoi_regions = []

    for i, point_region in enumerate(voronoi.point_region):
        region = voronoi.regions[point_region]
        vr = VoronoiRegion(point_region)
        for r in region:
            vr.add_vertex(r, voronoi.vertices)
        vr.point_inside = (i, voronoi.points[i])
        voronoi_regions.append(vr)
    return voronoi_regions


points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]])
vor = Voronoi(points)
regions = voronoi_to_voronoi_regions(vor)
for r in regions:
    print(r)
```

and result for [sample](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html):

```
region id=1[point:[0. 0.](point_id:0)], vertices: (inf)[0.5 0.5]
region id=3[point:[0. 1.](point_id:1)], vertices: (inf)[0.5 1.5][0.5 0.5]
region id=2[point:[0. 2.](point_id:2)], vertices: (inf)[0.5 1.5]
region id=8[point:[1. 0.](point_id:3)], vertices: (inf)[1.5 0.5][0.5 0.5]
region id=7[point:[1. 1.](point_id:4)], vertices: [0.5 0.5][0.5 1.5][1.5 1.5][1.5 0.5]
region id=9[point:[1. 2.](point_id:5)], vertices: (inf)[1.5 1.5][0.5 1.5]
region id=6[point:[2. 0.](point_id:6)], vertices: (inf)[1.5 0.5]
region id=4[point:[2. 1.](point_id:7)], vertices: (inf)[1.5 1.5][1.5 0.5]
region id=5[point:[2. 2.](point_id:8)], vertices: (inf)[1.5 1.5]
```